# export array to csv on wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, csv

I am trying to export an array to csv on wordpress. An excel sheet downloads however it doesn't have the correct data, and instead is populated with what looks like my functions.php file. This is my code:

```
 <?php       
      // How to Generate CSV File from Array in PHP Script       
      $results = array (  
           "0" => array(  
                "name"           => "Anna Smith",  
                "email_id"      => "annabsmith@inbound.plus"  
           ),  
           "1" => array(  
                "name"           => "Johnny Huck",  
                "email_id" => "johnnyohuck@inbound.plus"  
           )  
      );  
      $filename = 'userData.csv';       
      header("Content-type: text/csv");       
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");       
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");       
      $header = array_keys($results[0]);       
      fputcsv($output, $header);       
      foreach($results as $row)       
      {  
           fputcsv($output, $row);  
      }       
      fclose($output);       
 ?>
```

It is in a php file and linked to a page template through `<?php get_template_part('lib/page'); ?>`

The first line of the excel sheet looks like this: `<!DOCTYPE html><html class="no-js" lang="en-US"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"> <!--[if IE ]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge`

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to export from some plugin then you will have an export button so u can export or download the import /export plugin in WordPress it will help you to export all the flies from WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dheeraj, however I'm not trying to export from a plugin. I have an ecommerce website and I built a function to sort my sales into an array. I want to download this array as a csv.

Comment: There is an option to export the array